# Deallocation of Memory for Recursion

Tags: c++, function, recursion, memory-management, stack

We all know that a certain amount of memory is allocated when a function is calling itself recursively. So how can we deallocate that whole memory and return to the main function ? Also, wanted to know that how can we return from a recursion immediately to the calling function?

Comment: A normal return from a function "deallocates" the stack memory. There is nothing else you need to do. It is not clear to me what you intend to do or what problem you are trying to solve. Could you please provide a code example?

Comment: Probably a good idea not to begin a question with _"We all know"_, followed by a pretty blatant misunderstanding of how the stack works.  If I was to read between the lines, I might guess that you're trying to bail out of a recursion after encountering some unexpected error.  In this scenario, you could consider using exceptions if appropriate, along with a try-catch.  It could be much simpler though, if your function just returns a value that lets the caller know to return.  In other words: normal recursion.  I second the notion that you should show a code example and explain the problem.